# Check if number is square?

Tags: python, sage

Is there a function in Sage which checks if a rational number is a square? It is easy to write such a function but I would prefer to use an existing function because I don't want to copy so many self written function into each worksheet where I need them.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `is_square` method.

```
sage: a = 5/9
sage: a.is_square()
False
sage: b = 4/9
sage: b.is_square()
True
```

In addition, rather than copy-pasting a bunch of definitions
from one worksheet to another, you should put all your custom
functions in a file, say `my_stuff.sage`,
and load this file from the worksheets where you need that stuff.